# pagination in codeigniter and passing values to a function do not work

Tags: codeigniter

Controller

```
public function category($id = '') {
    $offset=..;

    $var = $this->pm->get_items_by_category($id,$offset,$start_row);
}
```

But in my view I have :

```
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url().'/welcome/category/2'; ?>">Mobile</a></li>
```

Comment: Which error do you have? That `$offset=..;` is just a typo or is in your real code?

Comment: no it is just a typo but the problem is generally when we pass values thro url in controllers function and ofcors that may be numeric and hence the pagination link be the same value.. is there any way to distinguish

Comment: You need to post much more code to understand where the problem is...have you already load the pagination library? http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you are trying to say but it's not very clear.

Your link needs to pass the limit and offset as well as the id. So do something like this

```
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url("welcome/category/$limit/$offset/$id");?>">Mobile</a></li>
```

Then in your controller set up your function like this.

```
public function category($limit, $offset, $id){

}
```

If you give more info I can give better answer.